# Primary address in Address

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

Does anybody know how to make a address primary in `VendTable`?

I need to make a new field (checkbox) in the Address tab of VendTable (the datasource for Address in VendTable comes from DirpartyAddressRelationship and Address).

Can anyone let me know step by step how to make a address primary?

There seems to be a lot of relations. I am not sure how this is working.

Comment: If you find the answer usefull, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are asking how to set the primary address using code (not through the user interface).

Use the `DirParty` class:

```
static void DirPartyTest(Args _args)
{
    VendTable v = VendTable::find("10000");
    DirParty d = DirParty::constructFromCommon(v);
    ;
    d.getDirPartyAddress().parmIsPrimary(NoYes::Yes);
    Dirparty::updateAddressFromParty(d);
}
```

Using a specific address:

```
void setPrimary(Address a)
{
    DirParty d = DirParty::constructFromCommon(a);
    ;
    d.getDirPartyAddress().parmIsPrimary(NoYes::Yes);
    Dirparty::updateAddressFromParty(d);
}
```